# How to set UIButton has been clicked when i initialize the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to set the UIButton has been clicked when i load the view just like the method 'setPressed' in android.I have tried setting 'selected' as YES, but didn't work. How can i do that?

Comment: Setting the `selected` property to `YES` is the correct course of action.  In what way did that not work?  Can you post your code?  Was the pointer to the button non-nil when when you set the selected property?

Comment: The method in the class is  '- (void)setclicked{ self.view.selected =YES; }'. The view here is a button  and i call this method by ' [melbourne setclicked];' in the view controller. In the demo, once i click the button, one alertview will appear. However, the alertview didn't appear when i initailize the view by doing so.

Comment: Are you saying you want to programmatically press a button, just as if the user had pressed it? If so, then use `[yourButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: when you say `self.view` it means the complete `view`. Have you created a subclass for `UIButton` under which you have written this code??

Comment: I will try sendActionsForControlEvents . I am using a third-party library and its naming for variables seems inappropriate such as 'view'.

Comment: `- (void)setclicked{
    [self.view sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view.selected?@"YES":@"NO");
    self.view.selected = YES;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.view.selected?@"YES":@"NO");
}` I change my code like this and the console shows 'NO YES'. The alertview still didn't show.